# Continuous polar equation of Sqrt spiral

Tags: geometry

Please help find polar coordinate equation  $ r =f(\theta) $ or $ \theta =g(r) $

where $r$ and $\theta$ are continuous functions of  $n$ as given:

[SqrtSpiral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66969/drawing-a-square-root-spiral)

EDIT1:

n is a discrete (discontinuous) variable ( n = 1,2,3..) with

$$ r_n = \sqrt n ;$$
$$ r_{n+1}^2 -r_n^2 = 1 ;  \\ r_n = \cot\Delta\theta =\cot (\theta_{n+1} - \theta_n );$$

All known spirals in the plane are either

$ r= f(\theta) $ or parametrically $ r(t),\theta(t), $

into which form Sqrt spiral is not castable.

I tried to adjust Pythogorean relation

$$ m^2+n^2 , m^2-n^2 , 2 m n $$

with no luck, so I posted here for help.

Comment: Do you want $r_n$ as a function of $\theta_n$?

Comment: @ marty cohen Yes, For (0, pi/4..) radii (1, sqrt 2,..)

Comment: Bounty for $r_n$ as a function of $θ_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the spiral of Theodorus. See here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus

for references. I particularly recommend the preprint to be found here:

http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~joergw/Papers/theopaper.html

Comment: OK.. actually my question is: Can Equn (12) in the above Waldvogel's paper be used to find all non-integral n′s for a given value of θ ?.. so that we can plot rn on y-axis as function of θ on x-axis as an independent variable?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a different approach to the continuous *sqrt* spiral that I was hoping would include all the points on the spiral of Theodorus. It does not quite do that for the initial points but it agrees very well as it approaches the spiral of Archimedes asymptotically for large $n$. I'll present the analysis here. Let me start with the discrete spiral of Theodorus, which I develop as follows:

$$r(n)=\sqrt{n}\\\Delta\theta(n)=\text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\\theta(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \Delta\theta(k)\\z(n)=r(n)e^{i\theta(n)}$$

Now, by a simple extension of the idea, let $t$ be a continuous variable and let

$$r(t)=\sqrt{t}\\d\theta(t)=\text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) dt\\\theta(t)=\int_0^t \text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) dt=\sqrt{t}+t\ \text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right) -\text{tan}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t}\right) \\z(t)=r(t)e^{i\theta(t)} $$

Let me digress for a moment to point out that as $t\to \infty$, $\theta(t)\to 2\sqrt{t}-\pi/2$, and $z(t)\to -i\sqrt{t} e^{-i\sqrt{t}}$, hence the spiral of Archimedes.

The figure below shows a comparison of the discrete spiral of Theodorus (circles) and the present *sqrt* spiral (line). Clearly, this continuous spiral does not include the spiral of Theodorus, but it is a definitely a sqrt spiral. (NOTE: the continuous spiral had to be rotated to align properly with the discrete one. I'm not exactly sure why that is.)

[image: Square Root Spirals]

Answer (score 0):

$r_{n+1}^2 -r_n^2 = 1 ;  \\ r_n = \cot\Delta\theta =\cot (\theta_{n+1} - \theta_n ) ;$

I'll write $t$ for $\theta$ since I'm lazy.

From your equations,
$\cot^2 (t_{n+2} - t_{n+1} ) 
=\cot^2 (t_{n+1} - t_n ) +1
$,
so
$t_{n+2}$
is a function of
$t_{n+1}$
and
$t_{n}
$.

Since
$\cot(a-b)
=\dfrac{1+\tan a \tan b}{\tan a -tan b}
$,
letting
$u_n
=\tan(t_n)
$,
$\dfrac{(1+u_{n+2} u_{n+1})^2}{(u_{n+2}-u_{n+1})^2}
=\dfrac{(1+u_{n+1} u_{n})^2}{(u_{n+1}-u_{n})^2}+1
$.
This is the relation among
the $u_i$.

Letting 
$g
=\dfrac{(1+u_{n+1} u_{n})^2}{(u_{n+1}-u_{n})^2}+1
$,
$(1+u_{n+2} u_{n+1})^2
=g(u_{n+2}-u_{n+1})^2
$
or,
letting
$p = u_{n+2}$
and
$q = u_{n+1}$,
$(1+pq)^2 = g(p-q)^2$
or
$1+2pq+p^2q^2
=g(p^2-2pq+q^2)
$
or
$p^2(q^2-g)
+p(2-2gq)
+gq^2-1
=0
$,
or
$p^2(q^2-g)
+2p(1-gq)
+gq^2-1
=0
$.

The discriminant of this
divided by $4$
 is

$\begin{array}\\
((1-gq)^2-(q^2-g)(gq^2-1)
&=(1-2gq+g^2q^2)-(gq^4-q^2(g^2+1)+g)\\
&=(1-2gq+g^2q^2)-(gq^4-q^2(g^2+1)+g)\\
&=1-2gq+g^2q^2-gq^4+q^2g^2+q^2-g\\
&=1-2gq+2g^2q^2-gq^4+q^2-g\\
\end{array}
$

I don't know where to go from here,
so I'll stop.